# Xamarin close the Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xcode8

Now I am Using Xamarin Version 6.1 and Xcode Version 8.0.

So when ever require and need to make any change in storyboard for existing project, I am opening storyboard file in Xcode.

So, first I have to select any device mandatorily and after making any change I will go back to Xamarin, Xcode will get closed.

Anybody also facing such issue?? In such scenario development is much complicated. Please help...

Thanks & Regards,

Hardik Shah

Comment: Does the log on the computer show anything that indicates something going wrong?

Comment: No am not getting any log in Xamarin. Normally, while we close xcode and go back to xamarin, xamarin will take update and close xcode  completely same looks am getting here. (Without closing xcode manually)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that they have changed the way it was working earlier.
Downgrading to Xcode 7 also created issues as it was not compatible with XCode 8 modified storyboards.

This is from Xamarin tech support on the issue:

The behavior of the Xamarin Studio synchronization for editing interface builder files with Xcode Interface Builder has unfortunately changed for Xcode 8 due to changes in Xcode. With Xcode 7.3 and earlier, Xamarin Studio could leave Xcode open when it performed the synchronization steps. (In fact, leaving Xcode open during the sync did cause certain problems, but at least it didn't usually cause Xcode to crash.) In contrast, starting with Xcode 8, if Xamarin Studio tries to use that same approach, it does cause Xcode 8 to crash. So rather than forcibly crashing Xcode, Xamarin Studio tells Xcode to quit.

To give a bit more historical context, the Xcode sync has always been quite problematic.

Reference Link: https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/16267411-do-not-require-xcode-8-to-quit-when-synchronizing

Bugzilla same issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44285

Some crucial comment:

The problem is that when you switch back to Xamarin Studio, it deletes the temporary project that it exported to Xcode which causes Xcode to crash (actually current versions tell Xcode to exit cleanly in order to avoid the crash).
I would recommend using Xamarin Studio's built-in iOS UI Designer instead. If that isn't good enough to use, then we'd prefer you tell us what bugs you need fixed in that and/or what features you need so that we can address your needs that way.
We are pushing to completely drop support for exporting to Xcode as it doesn't make sense to support 2 different ways of doing the same thing.

Hence, we will have to live or start adjusting with what they have implemented. I switched channel to alpha mode but no changes in the behavior.

We have two options:

1. Start using Xamarin Studio Designer and report bugs/features which are missing. They are confident that everything is ported. We have observed slowness issue
2. Open design file in Xcode 8 and go back to Xamarin only after changes are complete.

I hope this will helps you. Also keep posting here if you found better option or solution.